# Here Map instead of map tiles update store the map at once

Tags: android, here-api

Here Map folks, How to load the HERE Map for one time to particular state instead while travel map tiles update. Any Suggestion or Example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the [Premium](https://developer.here.com/develop/mobile-sdks) version of the SDK, it sounds like you want to use the [MapLoader API](https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/android-hybrid-plus/topics/maps-offline.html). In particular, `MapLoader#getMapPackages()` and `MapLoader#installMapPackages(List<Integer> packageIdList)`. More detailed API reference can be found [here](https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/android-hybrid-plus/topics_api_nlp_hybrid_plus/com-here-android-mpa-odml-maploader.html).

If you are using the [Starter](https://developer.here.com/develop/mobile-sdks) version of the SDK, you are out of luck. Offline caching of map data is not supported in the Starter version.

For more details on the usage of the `MapLoader` API you can see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35333711/275524