# Implement off line here map in android

Tags: android, here-api

I want to implement here map in my android application.I search about this in here map developer document and implement the map. But I want to implement off line options for this here map. How we implement here map off line option in our android application.  Is there any documentation available for off line implementation of here map?
Is there any sample code available for the same?

Comment: see here link: https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/android-hybrid-plus/topics/maps-offline.html

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35271228/here-api-offline-maps-installation/35333711#35333711

Answer (score 2):

If you are interested in using the engine in offline mode, first download some maps via the MapLoader API linked [here](https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/android-hybrid-plus/topics/maps-offline.html). Next set the MapEngine to offline mode by using the API linked [here](https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/android-hybrid-plus/topics_api_nlp_hybrid_plus/com-here-android-mpa-common-mapengine.html#topic-apiref__setonline-boolean)

Once the MapEngine is set to offline mode, all requests will be done offline. Everything from map rendering, routing, search to guidance. Note that the results obtained offline may not be as good as online mode.