# Add download offline map in Android with Here maps

Tags: android, maps, here-api

I have already developed an Android Here map which has a simple map view but I need to add offline support to the app, how can I add it to my app in order to let the user download a specific country or area?

Note that I implemented my app using the tutorial in the link below:
https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/android-hybrid-plus/topics/maps.html

Comment: Related answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35271228/here-api-offline-maps-installation/35333711#35333711

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the **[Offline Maps](https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/android-hybrid-plus/topics/maps-offline.html)** section of the mobile sdk documentation.

In particular, you might want to use the following methods of the `MapLoader` class:

> `installMapPackages(List<Integer> packageIdList)` - *To download and install new country or region data*
>
> `uninstallMapPackages(List<Integer> packageIdList)` - *To uninstall and delete country or region data that is no longer desired*

Comment: I added this method and listener for progress and completion called (MapLoader.Listener) and it triggers correctly for download completion but when I added 
`int mapPackageID;
 mapPackages.add(mapPackageID);
 mapLoader.installMapPackages(mapPackages);`

How can I know what the package ID for specific country?

Comment: As mentioned in Andrew's answer, you should use mapLoader.getMapPackages(); to get mapping between Package Titles (country name) and Pakcage Id

Comment: Is there a way to delete route or bounding box based downloaded data?