# installMapPackages of Current city

Tags: here-api

I read this doc
https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/ios-premium/topics/maps-offline.html

**installMapPackages**. ---> It is installing all map But I need to install map particular city **How to use this code for particular city.**

NMAMapPackage* root = self.mapLoader.rootPackage;

Ex- I am from India I need to download particular city map. Than How to download the particular city map.

```
 -(void)startInstall
{

 NMAMapPackage* root = self.mapLoader.rootPackage;
 [self refreshMapPackageTableWithArray:(NSMutableArray*)root.children];
}
- (void)refreshMapPackageTableWithArray:(NSMutableArray*)mapPackages
{
self.currentPackages = mapPackages;

NSArray *packageArray = [[NSArray alloc]
                         initWithObjects: self.currentPackages, nil];
[[NMAMapLoader sharedMapLoader]installMapPackages:packageArray];

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code, you are downloading the root map package which contains the entire world. `NMAMapPackage` is represented as a tree structure, so you have to search the package structure recursively to find the MapPackage you would like to install. You can do this using the `children` property of `NMAMapPackage` and looking at the `title` of the children.

Please see the links below for more info.

---

You can find an example app for map downloading on GitHub: [Map Downloader iOS](https://github.com/heremaps/here-ios-sdk-examples/tree/master/map-downloader-ios)

Similar Question on Stack Overflow: [HERE API Offline Maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35271228/here-api-offline-maps-installation/35333711#35333711)

[User Guide: Offline Maps (MapLoader)](https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/ios-premium/topics/maps-offline.html)

[API Reference: NMAMapPackage](https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/ios-premium/topics_api_nlp_hybrid_plus/interfacenmamappackage.html)

[API Reference: NMAMapLoader](https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/ios-premium/topics_api_nlp_hybrid_plus/interfacenmamaploader.html)

Comment: @thanks Andrew Jc link is helpful me But Can you share code in iOS  for any one country download which help I see how to get particular country  on map and their  children . I am using this but it  is return bool value [self.mapLoader getMapPackages]

Comment: Please look in detail at the example app from GitHub, it has the working code. `getMapPackages` is an asynchronous method, you have to listen for the result from `NMAMapLoaderDelegate` `mapLoader:didGetPackagesWithResult:` callback and then you can search for the package you want using `NMAMapLoader` `rootPackage` as described in the answer.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable answer I have found my answer